# Inserting Records Access MDB with OleDB

Tags: c#, oledb, jet

Why does this happen? :-S Short and simple this time round. Oh, I'm connecting to an MDB file (2007 Access).

Code:

```
public bool insertRecord(int SR_Number, string Serial_Number, string Model_Number, bool Chargeable, bool Priority, bool Rollback)
    {
        string cmdStr = "INSERT INTO Recovery_CD_Orders ([SR_Number], [Serial_Number], [Model_Number], [Chargeable], [Priority], [Agent_placing_order], [Rollback_reqd]) Values (@SR_Number, @Serial_Number, @Model_Number, @Chargeable, @Priority, @Agent_Placing_Order, @Rollback)";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(cmdStr, thisCon);

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("SR_Number", SR_Number);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Serial_Number", Serial_Number);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Model_Number", Model_Number);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Agent_Placing_Order", Environment.UserName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Chargeable", Chargeable);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Priority", Priority);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Rollback", Rollback);

        cmd.Connection.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cmd.Connection.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
        return true;
    }
```

Error:

```
Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
```

Table Layout:

```
SR_Number: Number
Serial_Number: Text
Model_Number: Text
Agent_Placing_Order: Text
Chargeable: Yes/No
Priority: Yes/No
Rollback: Yes/No
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to tell from what is presented in the question. I suspect the issue is with the AddWithValue type inference. Your best bet is to explicitly declare the types in old school fashion as that will tell access what to use.

Comment: Thanks for this, I'd actually taken that code from somewhere else and was trying to apply it. In the end I used the .Add method :-) Thanks for the pointer!